# List of strings, replace all words from other list

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

Python novice here.

I have a list of documents, and another list of search terms. I would now like to iterate over each document, and replace all occurrences of any of the search terms with something like `<placeholder>`. It should, however, only match full words, so `text.replace` probably does not work?

So, something like this:

```
document_list =  ['I like apples', 'I like bananas', 'I like apples and bananas and pineapples', 'I like oranges, but not blood oranges.']
search_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'blood oranges']

Out: ['I like <placeholder>', 'I like <placeholder>', 'I like <placeholder> and <placeholder> and pineapples', 'I like oranges, but not <placeholder>.']
```

Right now, I have something like

```
for document in document_list:
    for term in search_list:
        document = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(term),'<placeholder>',document)
```

This seems to work, but is really (and I mean *really*) slow.If I were to run this on my full dataset of ~10k documents, with a search_list of probably ~5k terms, it would take several days to finish. 
Is there any better way to approach this problem and make it faster?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit1: Maybe it's worth mentioning that the terms in `search_list`can also consist of multiple words. Edited the example accordingly.

Edit2: Thanks for pointing to the other thread, had not found that one before. Sorry about that. As mentioned below, I'd still be curious to hear other, non-regex solutions just to learn about them. The actual problem has been soved through the other thread, though. =)

Comment: Are you open to non-regex solutions?

Comment: Sure, I'm open for whatever works best. Regex was just the first (and only) thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility:

```
import re

document_list =  ['I like apples', 'I like bananas', 'I like apples and bananas and pineapples']
search_list = ['apples', 'bananas']

search_re = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(search_list) + r')\b')
replacement = r'<placeholder>'
document_replaced = [search_re.sub(replacement, doc) for doc in document_list]
print(*document_replaced, sep='\n)
```

Output:

```
I like <placeholder>
I like <placeholder>
I like <placeholder> and <placeholder> and pineapples
```